# Good ASP.NET excel-like Grid control?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, grid

We are looking for an ASP.NET compatible data grid that allows for multi-line editing similar to Excel or a WinForms data grid.  It must also support very basic keyboard input (tab, arrow keys, return).  Note that we are **not** looking for Excel capabilities (functions, formatting, formulas) ... just a grid for fast data entry.

I've looked at Telerik, Infragistics, ComponentOne, DevExpress, and many others ... all their support teams have said that the controls either do not support multi-line, or do so in such a clunky way that it would be unusable.

Has anyone used any Excel-like grids that they can recommend?  The client-side grids seemed closer to what we needed, with Sigma Widgets ( [example](http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_grid2/demos/example_column_editor.html) ) being the closest I've found so far.  Extjs's grid was too inflexible, and the jQuery grid was too buggy.

Comment: What do you mean by "inflexible" for ExtJS grid? It can be as flexible as you want it to be, given proper programming effort on extending it.

Comment: ExtJS has very little support for theming - the CSS is incredibly verbose.  We need to change the look/feel of the grid.  The ExtJS devs on their forum have basically said "changing your management's minds will be easier than changing the grid's look/feel, don't even attempt it" ... so ExtJS is out.

Comment: used obout grid for the same purpose, its pretty good and fast. hope this helps http://www.obout.com/grid/aspnet_commands_excel_style_autosave.aspx Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We ended up using [Sigma Grid](http://www.sigmawidgets.com/) ... thanks for all the other replies!

Comment: Did you get it to work with multi-line editing? That is, saving changes to multiple rows simultaneously?

Comment: This link now attempts to redirect to a facebook login page

Answer (score 16):

It does not exist today. There are products such as those you have mentioned which have tried, but in my experience none of them will make an experienced Excel user happy.

My company makes Excel compatible spreadsheet components for use with Windows Forms and ASP.NET. We have been getting this question for years, so we have of course considered building one because it looks like a good business. But HTML / JavaScript is just not a suitable platform for building something which "feels right" to users who want it to work like Excel - IMO.

We have settled on the idea of building a spreadsheet control for Silverlight. I believe this will give you the best of both worlds - cross platform rich interactive spreadsheet in the browser which any Excel user would be comfortable with. Unfortunately, that is not going to happen this month or next...

At my previous company, we actually built a spreadsheet component as a Netscape Plugin, as an ActiveX control and as a Java Applet. They had a little bit of success, but none of these technologies ever became ubiquitous in the enterprise for various reasons. I believe Microsoft is finally getting it right with Silverlight and that Silverlight will become the gold standard for browser based Line of Business applications in the Enterprise.

EDIT:

I should have mentioned that the product I alluded to above is Formula One / NET (Netscape Plugin released ~1995), Formula One / ActiveX and Formula One for Java - which is now sold by Actuate as e.Spreadsheet. I left in 2002, but AFAIK they still maintain the Java Applet which is probably the best example of an Excel like UI in the browser (I have no interest in the product any more - in fact we compete to some extent with e.Spreadsheet and intend to have a better answer with a Silverlight control in the future). I did not mention it by name in my original answer because it is a Java product - not a .NET product - but it is a potential answer even for an ASP.NET web site.

Lloyd Cotten correctly comments that Google Docs is an example of a spreadsheet built with HTML / JavaScript. Lloyd says Google Docs "definitely 'feels right' in its similarity to Excel". While I respect Lloyd's opinion, in my experience Google Docs does not 'feel right'. Perhaps this is because I'm a spreadsheet guy. I do know that we talk to potential customers almost every day who are trying to solve the problem of the OP, and they have all looked and cannot find one they are happy with - but of course they would not be calling us if they had so we are dealing with a biased sample and I understand that.

So I just want to clarify that there are in fact plenty of examples of HTML / JavaScript grids and spreadsheets which are usable. It's just that I don't want to have to use them because I expect certain keys to do certain things and a particular level of responsiveness which is just not there today with any of the HTML / JavaScript solutions I have tried (and I look at them regularly because my company could definitely sell such a product if it were feasible to build one that we could be proud of).

Comment: I know it's not ASP .NET but AFAIK, Google Docs spreadsheet uses HTML / Javascript and it definitely "feels right" in its similarity to Excel grid.  Not saying that Silverlight isn't the best choice for your company, but just pointing out that you can obtain pretty good results with JS / HTML.

Comment: We don't even need formulas and such ... just a grid with multi-line edit capabilities (with a "look/feel" similar to Excel).  Thanks for your feedback, BTW!

Comment: Lloyd Cotten - I've played with Google Docs from early on. We will have to agree to disagree. I would not want to have to use Google Docs on a regular basis or ask my users to use it. Of course, I understand that this is subjective. Maybe I have too many customers with 100MB+ workbooks...

Comment: LuckyLindy - I suppose the answer depends on just how Excel-like you want it to be. I've been building commercially available spreadsheets for DOS / Unix / Mac / Windows / .NET for a long time and I'm biased in favor of a real programming language with a real UI - at least for spreadsheets.

Comment: @Joe Erickson: I meant no disrespect to what your company provides and Google Docs definitely won't work for everybody, but for some situations (such as the original author) a Google Docs -like functionality may work and perhaps may be best.

Comment: Lloyd Cotten - No disrespect taken and I certainly respect the opinion of anyone who disagrees with me on this issue. There is not a right & wrong - but I do believe that most people who spend a lot of time with Excel are not going to be happy with HTML / JavaScript based apps.

Comment: Wow.. Not exist today. That's a very bold statement. There are already  various open source and commercial component that provides grid multi line editing and keyboard navigation. Several of them has been listed below.

Answer (score 4):

How about [FarPoint Spread](http://www.fpoint.com/netproducts/spreadweb/spread.aspx)?
I'm in the middle on evaluating FarPoint Spread for ASP.NET, and so far I've been happy with the result.

Comment: I agree....I recently went through the same thing, and I found the Farpoint Spread to be pretty much the only one that can mimic excel.  It actually does it quite well, and programming against it is quite easy and intuitive.

Comment: The linked page just reports a server error now

Answer (score 3):

Well.. not sure, but I am looking for something similar and I found:

[Nitobi](http://www.nitobi.com/products/completeui/demos/explorer/index.html)

Not sure if it does exactly what you want, although youcan definately move around with cursor keys, and edit inline....

EDIT
Also Essential Objects have a good editor too... seems very like excel...
http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Default.aspx?path=Grid_i1_i20

Comment: Nitobi definitely looks interesting - have you used it on any projects?

Comment: This link is dead, the domain name appears to have expired

Answer (score 2):

[RealWorld Grid](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattdotson/articles/490868.aspx) is probably what you are looking for. I'm using it in my projects, and it works perfectly.

Here's their [CooglePlex page](http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNetRealWorldContr)

I don't think it supports the arrow keys, but it makes multirow editing a breeze.

p.s. seems like you're looking for client-side grids ... this one is server-side. I'll leave the comment there, somebody might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Infragistics grid with success. However, the learning curve is huge (and there's practically no support) and I don't know if there is multi-line editing.

Comment: Thanks - I liked the look of the grid, but their support team confirmed that there was no decent multi-line editing.

Comment: I have also used this grid for excel like data entry...although not multi-line either.
Infragistics provide some neat "editors" that can handle all the validation of cells etc
Getting the "arrow" key functionality to mirror excel though is a ridiculous task though...

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Syncfusion's](http://samples.syncfusion.com/ASPNET/7.1.0.21/Web/Grid.grouping.web/samples/3.5/CRUDOperations/ExcelLikeEdit/CS/ExcelLikeEdit.aspx) components and they're quite good, they boast an "Excel-like" editor, though I didn't see multi-line mentioned.

Comment: Close, but not quite.  Looks great, but every time I tabbed it tabbed out of the grid, arrow keys did not work, and for some reason there were long waits while editing at times.  Strange.  Thanks for the feedback though, I REALLY appreciate it!

Comment: This link is dead (404) but the site itself is still up. Maybe the relevant content still exists, but has moved?

Answer (score 1):

For intranet and IE users Office Web components can be an option. While flying in the face of all things a good web application should be, they let users feel at home in office on the web.

I had great success using the pivot table control combined with MS OLAP a few years ago.  User loved it and no wheels needed to be reinvented.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=982B0359-0A86-4FB2-A7EE-5F3A499515DD&displaylang=EN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164070.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Excel Like GridView](https://web.archive.org/web/20090428090017/http://www.aspboy.com/Categories/GridArticles/Excel_Like_GridView.aspx) allows for multiline editing and navigating using the arrow keys, as well as resizing columns and rows.

http://darkroastjava.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/creating-an-excel-like-grid-for-asp-net/ is an extension of that which also supports pasting multi-cell values from the clipboard.

Unfortunately, both only work in IE so far, but that meets my personal needs at this point of time.

Comment: The aspboy.com link is dead – looks like either the domain or the hosting has expired

Answer (score 1):

I think http://codethat.com/grid/ is quite good!

Comment: This link is dead, the domain has expired

Answer (score 0):

[dhtmlxGrid](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml) (client-side, JavaScript grid) supports multiline feature ([demo](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/16_rows_columns_manipulations/03_grid_multiline_col.html)), keyboard navigation and comes with server-side connector for ASP.NET. In case, someone is still looking for such a grid. Disclosure: I'm a part of the DHTMLX team.