# Web Grid, Client side Binding VS. Server side HTML generation

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview, jqgrid

I'm working on replacing an existing web grid in an ASP.NET web application, with a new implementation. The existing grid is powerful, but not flexible enough. It also brings with it all kind of frameworks we don't like to have on our web pages.

While looking into existing options I noticed I can break the available solutions into two main approaches. The older approach is represented best by the ASP.NET GridView. This is a classic ASP.NET control that generates the needed HTML on the server, based on a given set of data. The newer approach is depending on client side rendering, mainly with jQuery. A good example would be [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). Only the data is sent to the client (Usually with JSON or XML)

In the GridView case, if I want an AJAX behavior, I would have to implement it with something like an update panel.

- Is there a definitive choice I should make?
- Is there a good chance of achieving the same snappy behavior I get with jqGrid (even with many records), with server side rendered controls?
- Is there some hybrid implementation incorporating both approaches?

Comment: Beware of jqGrid, we adopted it in a project but had to walk away from it subsequently, because it is lacking extensibility (whatever you have in the demos will work, but once you need to change it even a little bit or have something more, you need to get under the hood of the jqGrid and get your hands really dirty, can't build an extension and just plug it in).

Comment: Odd. I've had no problems customizing jqGrid at all.

Comment: Depends on the level of customization, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no definitive choice you should make, but it's worth noting
   that changing to client-side AJAX controls is a pretty big paradigm
   shift that will require you to rethink how you do nearly everything
   with the grid.
2. Going half-way (by using a server-side control such as `GridView`
   in an `UpdatePanel`) will likely improve the user experience, since
   the page will still be visible and responsive while it's updating. But
   the `UpdatePanel`-style is still clunky compared to the new client-only 
   grids, because this technique sends all the page's form data when it posts back
   (including all that ViewState in the `GridView`, if ViewState is turned
   on). One brief note of caution: `GridView` is not compatible with
   `UpdatePanel` when `GridView.EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks` is set to true.
3. I haven't used any of they hybrid implementations (such as Coolite's Ext wrappers for .NET), but they are out there. There was at least [one good SO discussion about this topic and the different grids available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732355/jquery-gridview-control).

Answer (score 1):

I am also evaluating jgGrid vs. Gridview. I am just interested in the performance and efficiency of the grid. Even though jqGrid has a bit learning curve, I can invest some time in learning if it can provide great improvement in performance when compared to gridview. Can any expert throw more light on this topic?. Thank you very much.

Comment: moved to jqGrid a while ago, and I'm very happy with the results. There is a learning curve. But after all, it is very powerful and flexible. It feels to me that I'm in control again of the behavior and performance of my application