# How to update an datagrid with webmethods

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

I choose the method to update my data every second with a javascript PageMethod and  WebMethod.

With much returns via an object I can set hunderts of labels if it is naeccasery.

The time for 2 completedatabase-querys is unter 200 Milliseconds and the Post-Weight is wunderfull low!

But how I can databind my gridview in a webmethod?

Is there a way to bind it in JavaScript of how can I access it with a static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely use AJAX and web services to display tabular data (grids) in your ASP.NET applications. These StackOverflow questions offer a good introduction to several different options:

- [Web Grid, Client side Binding VS. Server side HTML generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127459/web-grid-client-side-binding-vs-server-side-html-generation)
- [JQuery GridView control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732355/jquery-gridview-control)

However, you cannot literally databind [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) or [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) controls in javascript functions. The grid controls are server-side objects, deeply integrated into [the ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

ASP.NET controls only exist inside `Page` **instances** - and no page instance is created during the execution of static WebMethods. For a great explanation of this, see [Why do ASP.NET AJAX page methods have to be static?](http://encosia.com/2008/04/16/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)