# Populate GridView from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GenerateHtml(string id)
{
    //return id;
    DataView vwMain2;
    try
    {
        DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
        using (IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection())
        {
            string sSQL;
            sSQL = "select top 20                " + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " ASSISTING_FILE_ID, DATE_ENTERED, CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM, PRIMARY_INSURED, PRIMARY_CLAIMANT, LOB_ID, FILE_STATUS, BRANCH_NAME," + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " OWNERS_FIRST_NAME, OWNERS_LAST_NAME, OWNERS_NAME, OWNERS_EMAIL, OWNERS_OFFICE_PHONE, OWNERS_FAX_PHONE, OWNERS_CELL_PHONE" + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + "  from vwFILES_DetailViewWithOwners" + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " where 1 = 1                    " + ControlChars.CrLf;
            //+ " where 1 = 1 and WEB_USER_ID = '" + Security.USER_ID.ToString() + "'" + ControlChars.CrLf;
            using (IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL;

                using (DbDataAdapter da = dbf.CreateDataAdapter())
                {
                    ((IDbDataAdapter)da).SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        vwMain2 = dt.DefaultView;
                        GridView2.DataSource = vwMain2;

                            GridView2.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SplendidError.SystemError(new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0), ex.Message);
        //lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }

}
```

I have the following in my ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>
```

When I try to reference `GridView2` in my code behind, it says, "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property GridView2."

How can I resolve this issue so that I can create my grid view when `GenerateHtml` is called, or **is there a better way?**

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? Does it happen when you try to assign the view to the datasource, or does it happen when you call DataBind?

Comment: As a general remark. Make sure to use Sql Parameters rather than directly inputting strings into your sql statement. Otherwise someone might do a 'where 1 =1', and sql-inject attack your db.

Comment: @dave823 It happens at both references to `GridView2`.

Comment: is the error happening at compile time, or runtime? It kind of sounds like there is some disconnect between your aspx page, codebehind, or designer file

Comment: @dave823 When I try to compile.

Comment: ok thanks. Is there a reason your 'GenerateHtml' method is static? Are you calling this method from the codebehind page_load or some button click event, or is it a custom class that you are calling? If this method isn't directly in the page codebehind you will have to pass the GridView object in as a parameter

Comment: @dave823 How can I pass the object as a parameter?  What would my method head look like?

Comment: I'm sorry i did not realize this was a web method. i'm guessing you are calling this method with javascript/ajax. I don't think it is possible to bind to a control such as GridView this way. You can get the data back to the screen, but just not in a GridView. The other poster posted a good link with ideas for alternatives to GridView in this senario.

Comment: That's what I was wondering.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not have a reference to any page element when calling a WebMethod. Remember, you are calling a *static* method. For access to any page-level elements in code-behind you must go through the .NET page lifecyle, where all the "magic" happens.

Take a look at this SO question to find out how to do what you want: [How to update an datagrid with webmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764451/how-to-update-an-datagrid-with-webmethods)

Comment: So, I've looked at the link (and the links within it) and it looks like it is not possible to update the grid via Web Method?

Comment: It shows me how to do it with jqGrid, but not with GridView in ASP.NET.

Comment: There are _a lot_ of examples on that page and all the subsequent pages linked from there. _A LOT_. I highly doubt you went through all of them in the minute it took you to respond. That said, the only way I know to use a GridView and have AJAX-ish functionality is using an UpdatePanel.

Comment: I may not have gone through all of them but I, too, read that UpdatePanel is probably the only way to do this...  Not sure if I want to use that, though.

Comment: I agree 100%. I personally do not like UpdatePanels much myself. However, the question of how to do this has been answered many times on SO. _The answer is out there_ ;)