# Bind my asp.net grid view with javascript using ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to know how , if possible to bind my gridview from javascript in asp.net web forms.

My goal is to click a linkbutton which is in my grid view and it opens up a modalpopup
which populates a grid view in that modalpopup.

Hopefully my code snips explain my problem :

aspx:

```
           <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" ShowHeader="true" Visible="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubmitClaim" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hypLinkSubmit") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
```

cs: in the "protected void dgEC_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)" method:

```
      Claim ec1 = e.Row.DataItem as Claim;
      LinkButton lnkSubmit = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkSubmitClaim");
      lnkSubmit.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
      lnkSubmit.OnClientClick = String.Format("javascript:ShowPopup({0},{1})", "'" + ec1.GUID + "'", "'" + ec1.Claim_Number + "'");
```

...

```
    public string BindClaim(string claimNo)
    {
        dgPopUpClaims.DataSource = service.Get_Claim_Approvals(claimNo);
        dgPopUpClaims.DataBind();
        return "";
    }
```

js:

```
    function ShowPopup(guid, claimNo) {
        $find("ModalPopupExtenderClaim").show();
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnGUID.ClientID %>').value = guid;
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnClaimNo.ClientID %>').value = claimNo;
        var bla = document.getElementById('<%= BindClaim() %>');
    }
```

I retrieve a list of Approval_Item Objects from my webservice...

```
public class Approval_Item
{
    public string Employee_Number { get; set; }
    public string Employee_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can i do this from javascript and update the ajax modalpopup datagrid ?

If not how could i pass the claimNo parameter to the BindClaim() method ?

Hope my question is somewhat understandable, i am new to ajax , so any advice and perhaps resources/links to help further my understanding would be very much appreciated....

Thanking you in advance...
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this post [How to update an datagrid with webmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764451/how-to-update-an-datagrid-with-webmethods)

Comment: Thanks for the link , will follow it later today and see if it workd , is there no chance i could pass the parameter into the method here : 
var bla = document.getElementById('<%= BindClaim(claimNo) %>'); ?
Think i will need to do some researching and practicing with ajax....

Thanks again for link , will check it out and mark as answer should it solve my issue

Comment: Yup do some more research and take some tutorials. Calling BindClaim that way wont do anything really.