# Grid View using javascript or in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hai,

I need a simple grid view with horizontal and vertical scroll bar using Jquery or simple javascript or in php, can anyone suggest me a simple grid view plugin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732355/jquery-gridview-control

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExtJs like the second grid on http://www.extjs.com/playpen/ext-2.0/examples/grid/grid3.html

Look javascript source (http://www.extjs.com/playpen/ext-2.0/examples/grid/grid3.js) where "var grid2 =" begins at line 63